# PostgreSQL Check Constraint if concerned column is nullable

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, check-constraints

I have the sample table definition below. Is it possible to create a check constraint wherein the column affected can be nullable?

```
CREATE TABLE task (
    # other definition
    registered_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    completed_date timestamp without time zone
    # constraints
);
```

I was planning to imply a constraint check on `completed_date` so that the input value won't be lesser than `registered_date`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Check constraints accept NULL values automatically. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS)

> It should be noted that a **check constraint is satisfied if the check
>   expression evaluates to true or the null value**. Since most expressions
>   will evaluate to the null value if any operand is null, they will not
>   prevent null values in the constrained columns. To ensure that a
>   column does not contain null values, the not-null constraint described
>   in the next section can be used.

Bold emphasis mine.